# Is there a way to create a react carousel that pages through a dataset?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have found quite a few react carousels that scroll images but I need one that scrolls through a large data set and includes pagination.

Anyone know of any examples?

Answer (score 1):

For having an image slideshow with pagination, you need to combine both react carousel and react pagination.

I don't think there is any library that does both carousels and pagination.
Just use any pagination module with carousels on each page having fixed no of slideshow images.

Instead of content on each page, put carousels and pass the value through props.

Comment: But it is not with images but data. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can replace data with images?

Comment: Is that possible? The data comes from an API

Comment: after retrieving data from the API, you can present it in any way